# Difference between a class property and a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I am newbie in vba but I already searched on google but didnt find any good answer for this... For example why I would use a class to save a name of something instead of using a variable string?

Comment: "why I would use a class to save a name of something instead of using a variable string" - does not make sense.

Comment: You wouldn't use a class just for storing a variable.  A class is a template of code for an object that is used in other code.  [Here is a pretty good link for more information](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx)

Comment: VBA does not support classes as other OOP languages. Through VBA class you can "extend" MS Office objects, such as application object, by adding custom properties and methods(functions), etc.

Comment: Portland Runner exactly this wrbsite that I read about vba classes. Why I would create a name property or a salary property if Ican create a variable instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why you might use a class property instead of a variable, we need to start simple.

Suppose I am using Excel to hold an employee database.  I might have code like this:

```
Sub Demo1()  

  Dim EmpName As String
  Dim EmpId As String
  Dim EmpDateOfBirth As Date
  Dim EmpMgrId As String

  EmpName = "Smith, John"
  EmpId = "S024"
  EmpDateOfBirth = DateSerial(1991, 5, 20)
  EmpMgrId = "B012"

End Sub
```

I have simple variables for the four properties of an employee.  Here I have used simple assignments but in a real program I would input Name, Date of birth and Manager Id from the user and have code to generate the Employee Id.

If I want to produce a report of the new employee, I might want the name of the manager.  Certainly I would want to check that the Manager Id exists.  I might have code like this:

```
Sub Demo2()

  Const ColEmpId As Long = 1
  Const ColEmpName As Long = 2

  Dim EmpName As String
  Dim EmpId As String
  Dim EmpDateOfBirth As Date
  Dim EmpMgrId As String

  Dim MgrName As String
  Dim MgrId As String

  Dim RngCrnt As Range

  EmpName = "Smith, John"
  EmpId = "S024"
  EmpDateOfBirth = DateSerial(1991, 5, 20)
  EmpMgrId = "B012"

  Set RngCrnt = Columns(ColEmpId).Find(What:=EmpMgrId)
  If RngCrnt Is Nothing Then
    ' Manager Id not found
  Else
    Debug.Assert False
    MgrId = Cells(RngCrnt.Row, ColEmpId).Value
    MgrName = Cells(RngCrnt.Row, ColEmpName).Value
  End If

  ' Have information for report on new employee

End Sub
```

This is getting a bit messy and I only processing two employees.  What if I want to load my entire employee database into memory?  I would need arrays:

```
  Dim EmpName() As String
  Dim EmpId() As String
  Dim EmpDateOfBirth() As Date
  Dim EmpMgrId() As String
  Dim InxEmpNew as Long
  Dim InxMgr as Long
```

The first step towards making this more manageable is to use what most programming languages call a Structure but VBA calls a User Type or simply Type.

```
Type sEmp
  Name As String
  Id As String
  DoB As Date
  MgrId As String
End Type
```

This defines a new type of variable call `sEmp`.  (Note 1: the Type definition must be before any subs and functions. Note 2: the leading "s" is my convention and is not required.) I can now declare instances of `sEmp` with a `Dim` statement:

```
Sub Demo3()

  Const ColEmpId As Long = 1
  Const ColEmpName As Long = 2

  Dim NewEmp As sEmp
  Dim Mgr As sEmp
  Dim Emp() As sEmp      ' Not used but shows it is possble

  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  NewEmp.Name = "Smith, John"
  NewEmp.Id = "S024"
  NewEmp.DoB = DateSerial(1991, 5, 20)
  NewEmp.MgrId = "B012"

  RowCrnt = Columns(ColEmpId).Find(What:=NewEmp.MgrId).Row
  Mgr.Id = Cells(RowCrnt, ColEmpId).Value
  Mgr.Name = Cells(RowCrnt, ColEmpName).Value

  ' Have information for report on new employee

End Sub
```

With this simple example, the advantages of a user type are not very obvious.  However, User Types can be nested:

```
Type sName
  Given As String
  Family As String
End Type

Type sEmp
  Name As sName
  Id As String
  DoB As Date
  MgrId As String
End Type

Sub Demo4()

  Dim NewEmp As sEmp

  NewEmp.Name.Family = "Smith"
  NewEmp.Name.Given = "John"
  NewEmp.Id = "S024"
  NewEmp.DoB = DateSerial(1991, 5, 20)
  NewEmp.MgrId = "B012"

End Sub
```

This is still fairly simple but I believe it gives a hint of what is possible. User Types can be nested and can contain arrays.  You can create structures of almost any complexity and have them manageable in way that would be impossible without User Types.

For all other languages I know, Classes are a step up from Structures.  A Class gives you all the power of a Structure plus the ability to associate code with the Class.  This is not true of VBA. A VBA Class allows you to associate code with it but you lose a lot of the power of the User Type.

Many would not agree but I do not use Excel VBA Classes because if a problem is complex enough to need a Class:

1. I will probably want a proper database
2. The problem is too complex for VBA.

Comment: so, basically, is just a matter of organization... And what about memory and speed? Do you think that I can optimize this using classes?

Comment: I have never attempted to compare speed or memory usage.  I value my time to get a macro working reliably more than shaving a few seconds off run time or saving a few bytes.  If the task was so big that speed and/or memory usage become issues, I would not use VBA.